# I am doing JavaScript validation but it's not working properly when I enter last name, it does not display error and submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
        function check_validation()
        {
            var Fname = document.frm.Fname.value;
            var Lname = document.frm.Lname.value;
            var error = 0;
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = '';
            if (Fname == "")
            {
                var error = 1;
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'First name is required';
            }
            else
            {
               var error = 0;
            }
            if(Lname == "")
            {
                var error = 1;
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'Last name is required';
            }
            else
            {
                var error = 0;
            }
            if(error == 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>


<body>
    <div id="error">
    </div>
    <form name="frm">
        First name : <input type="text" name="Fname" />
        Last name : <input type="text" name="Lname" />

        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return check_validation();" />
    </form>
</body>
```

The validation is working properly when both values are empty but form is submitted when I directly enter second value in form. I can't find the error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are resetting the error flag if the last value is valid, so all other validation states are lost.

Assume `Fname` is blank, then error is set to `1`, but then if `Lname` is filled, you are setting the value of `error` back to `0`, so the last validation state check will consider only the validation state of `Lname` all previous states are ignored.

The solution is to set the flags initial value at the beginning, then only update the flag if the value is invalid as shown below. Also if you use `true/false` values for the flag then there is no need to use another `if...else` block at the bottom.

```
function check_validation() {
    var Fname = document.frm.Fname.value;
    var Lname = document.frm.Lname.value;
    var valid = true;
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = '';
    if (Fname == "") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'First name is required';
    }
    if (Lname == "") {
        valid = false;
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'Last name is required';
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping really very helpful to me and thank you so much for this help because i have to implemented on server.

Answer (score 0):

You set error to 0 if the second one is correct, disregarding of the value of the first one. By the way, instead of using 0/1 you should use booleans, that is exactly their purpose. Also don't set error more than one time (just don't use `var` when the var is already initialize).

```
function check_validation()
        {
            var Fname = document.frm.Fname.value;
            var Lname = document.frm.Lname.value;
            var error = true;
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = '';
            if (Fname == "")
            {
                error = true;
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'First name is required';
            }
            if(Lname == "")
            {
                error = true;
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += 'Last name is required';
            }
            return error;
        }
```